# Java: why isn't my code working? issue with charAt ().

Tags: java

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Degrees
{

    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
        sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
        if(sentence.indexOf("cat") != -1)
        {
            int lastInt = sentence.lastIndexOf("cat");
            lastInt= lastInt + 1;
            switch(charAt(lastInt))
            {
            case "":
            case ".":
            case ",":
            case "!":
            case "?":
            case "/":
            case ")":
            case "(":
                System.out.println("the profane word cat was found");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is, there is an error showing up for charAt(). the error says, "The method charAt(int) is undefined for the type Degrees". How can I get rid of this error and what is causing it?

Additional information on the code:

This code is supposed to find the profane word cat in sentences. However if the profane word is with in a word for example concatenate, then no profanity is detected. Also if we had the string , "concatenate the cat", the second cat shouldn't be considered profane. You are only responsible for evaluating the first occurrence of the word. If you have any suggestions for improving my code so it does what it should then please feel free to tell me how to improve it.

Comment: Call method properly: `sentence.charAt(index)`

Comment: `charAt` is an instance method of the `String` class.

Comment: now I have another error, this time it's on the cases. It says, "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to char". Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You must apply the charAt() method to a string, sentence in your case ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is scope, or your lack of appreciation of it.

```
charAt(index)
```

The scope for the above is the default scope, which is the scope of the class `Degrees` which you have defined. You have not defined a method `charAt`.

The correct answer is to adjust the scope of the call by adding the correct calling reference:

```
sentence.charAt(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

```
      int lastInt = sentence.lastIndexOf("cat");
        lastInt= lastInt + 1;
        switch(charAt(lastInt))
```

`charAt` needs to be called on `sentance`. And, assuming you want to look at the character *after* `"cat"` you need to add the length of the `"cat"` to the index, since it points to the start of the found substring.

```
      int lastInt = sentence.lastIndexOf("cat");
        lastInt= lastInt + "cat".length();
        switch(sentence.charAt(lastInt))
```